# How to run a member function in QtConcurrent in QT6

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

i try to run a member function with QtConcurrent. I am just learning c++ and qt and i used the way i found in their official documentation: https://wiki.qt.io/QtConcurrent-run-member-function

mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "testclass.h"

#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

void testFunction()
{
    qDebug() << "runs";
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    TestClass testClass;

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QtConcurrent::run(&this->testClass, &TestClass::start);
}
```

testClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class TestClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public:
    void start();

};

#endif // TESTCLASS_H
```

testClass.cpp

```
#include "testclass.h"

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

TestClass::TestClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void TestClass::start()
{
    qDebug() << "run" << QThread::currentThread();
}
```

I do not know where the problem is, but when i try to build i get following errors:

```
error: 'operator()' is not a member of 'std::decay<TestClass*>::type' {aka 'TestClass*'}
 struct ArgResolver : ArgResolver<decltype(&std::decay_t<F>::operator())>

error: no type named 'IsPromise' in 'struct QtPrivate::ArgResolver<TestClass*>'

error: no type named 'PromiseType' in 'struct QtPrivate::ArgResolver<TestClass*>'

error: no type named 'PromiseType' in 'struct QtPrivate::ArgResolver<TestClass*>'
         return (new StoredFunctionCallWithPromise<Function, PromiseType, Args...>(std::move(args)))
```

mainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "testclass.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    TestClass testClass;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where did you define your class member `testclass`? And please don't say in the ctor of MainWindow...

Comment: @chehrlic Hey, i do not know what ctor means. I created an instance of TestClass in the constructor of MainWindow, you can see it above. OOps, why is that not allowed?

Comment: "ctor" ... abbr. for "constructor" ("dtor" ... abbr. for "destructor")

Comment: `TestClass testClass;` is a local variable in your constructor `MainWindow::MainWindow()`. Concerning this, a constructor behaves like any function: Once you leave the constructor, `testClass` (like any local variable) is auto-destructed.

Comment: `TestClass testClass;` in the constructor creates a locally scoped variable that will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope.  Please show the class definition for `MainWindow`.

Comment: @G.M. I have posted the mainWindow.h in an answer.

Comment: @Yata Please use the [edit] facility to add the code to your question rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: @G.M. I understand what my problem is, but i have no clue how to do it right, i tried to use the constructor list of mainwindow but the erros do not change.

Comment: After a bit of searching it appears that the parameter order has changed from [`Qt5`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions) to [`Qt6`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions) (words fail me!) so I think you need `QtConcurrent::run(&TestClass::start, &this->testClass);` .

Answer (score 1):

In Qt6 , [Changes to Qt Concurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/concurrent-changes-qt6.html) says

> QtConcurrent::run() has been improved to work with a variable number
> of arguments, so the signatures are changed to:
>
> // run template

> QFuture run(Function &&f, Args
> &&...args)
>
> As a side effect, if f is a pointer to **a member function, the first**
> **argument of args should be the object for which that member is defined**
> (or a reference, or a pointer to it). So instead of writing:
>
> QImage image = ...;

> QFuture future = QtConcurrent::run(&image,
> &QImage::invertPixels, QImage::InvertRgba); You have to write:
>
> QFuture future = QtConcurrent::run(&QImage::invertPixels,
> &image, QImage::InvertRgba);

So as commented , the right call syntax is to pass the object name after the function pointer:

```
QtConcurrent::run(&TestClass::start, &this->testClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also encountered the same problem. Some changes have taken place in QT6 qtconcurrent. The parameter order of class member function calls should be like this:

```cpp
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&QImage::invertPixels, &image, QImage::InvertRgba);
```